Ros2 Nav2 issues : Robot not able to autonomously follow path correctly
I am trying to develop a robot and firstly I wanted to implement the nav2 stack in it. Its a custom designed robot and everything is working fine untill I run the autonomous navigation. In that I am facing multiple issues that I can see currently, they are:

After some time the laser data does not seem to be correct. It basically just jumps all over the place which further leads problems in planning the path.
In narrow spaces, robot is not able to turn smoothly. However, enough space is there for it to navigate through
While turning, it tries to turn like it is a ackerman steering model but actually its a differential drive robot, which i have set in the nav2_params file.

I think there are some more issues that are there like controller server warning in terminal can be seen like frequency is not as per desired frequency.
I am running ros2 humble on ubuntu 22.04.
Attaching a video for the same for more references and problems I am facing. If anyone knows the solution, please do let me know.
Screen recording of nav2

I'm going to wager it has to do with your simulation running at less than 30% real time seped.
